# Expo React Native - How to use ErrorRecovery?

Tags: react-native, expo

The current [Expo ErrorRecovery docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/error-recovery/) do not provide any example using `ErrorRecovery.setRecoveryProps()`.

If you know how to use it the **Managed workflow**, so that it catches JS errors, let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";
import * as ErrorRecovery from "expo-error-recovery";

export default function App({ exp }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{JSON.stringify(exp.errorRecovery)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          ErrorRecovery.setRecoveryProps({ info: "User pressed crash button" });
          throw "Crash!";
        }}
      >
        Crash!
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

When you load the app initially, `exp.errorRecovery` will be null. If you click the "`Crash!`" button and reload then `exp.errorRecovery` will contain whatever you set with `setRecoveryProps()`.

I think the idea is that you can use `setRecoveryProps()` to let your app know that it crashed and maybe provide some context about what happened just before the crash. I’ve never used it, though, so I’m not sure what a good use case is.

EDIT:

The above might not be all that useful, but you can combine it with the approach shown [here](https://medium.com/@benhurott/dealing-with-global-errors-in-react-native-expo-as-simple-as-possible-bc8e440caeae) (using a global error handler) to pass some information about the crash to the reloaded app:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";
import * as ErrorRecovery from "expo-error-recovery";

const defaultErrorHandler = ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler();

const globalErrorHandler = (err, isFatal) => {
  console.log("globalErrorHandler called!");
  ErrorRecovery.setRecoveryProps({ info: err });
  defaultErrorHandler(err, isFatal);
};

ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(globalErrorHandler);

export default function App({ exp }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{JSON.stringify(exp.errorRecovery)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          throw "Crash!";
        }}
      >
        Crash!
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, this is from the [expo ErrorRecovery source code](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-error-recovery/src/ErrorRecovery.fx.ts), so its essentially doing the same thing as the link you posted in your edit

```
import { canUseDOM } from 'fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import { getRecoveryPropsToSave } from './ErroRecoveryStore';
import ExpoErrorRecovery from './ExpoErrorRecovery';

if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
  const globalHandler = ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler();
  // ErrorUtils came from react-native
  // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/Libraries/vendor/core/ErrorUtils.js#L25
  ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(async (error, isFatal) => {
    if (ExpoErrorRecovery.saveRecoveryProps) {
      await ExpoErrorRecovery.saveRecoveryProps(getRecoveryPropsToSave());
    }
    globalHandler(error, isFatal);
  });
} else if (Platform.OS === 'web' && canUseDOM) {
  window.addEventListener('error', () => {
    ExpoErrorRecovery.saveRecoveryProps(getRecoveryPropsToSave());
  });
}
```